# How to exclude class from Xidel output

Tags: html, web-scraping, xidel

I want to refine my Xidel output using the xpath: **//BODY/DIV** by removing the lines containing "AClass", and keep the lines with "MyClass" only

Can I add line break to Xidel output file?

```
<a class="AClass" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/file1" target="_blank"> File1 </a>    
<a class="AClass" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/file2" target="_blank"> File2 </a>    
<a class="AClass" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/file3" target="_blank"> File3 </a>
<a class="AClass" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/file4" target="_blank"> File4 </a>
<a class="MyClass" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/file5" target="_blank"> File5 </a>
<a class="AClass" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/file6" target="_blank"> File6 </a>
<a class="MyClass" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/file7" target="_blank"> File7 </a>
```

Comment: Which XPath expression are you using exactly? `//body/div` would return a list of `div`s, not `a`s. Generally filtering can be done with `[]` or alternatively `except`

Answer (score 0):

To exclude an attribute with XQuery we can use regular inequation, in your example it would be `//a[@class !="AClass"]`.

This matches all `<a>`, regardless of depth, containing the attribute class **which** isn't equal to `AClass`.

As for your other question, about adding line breaks to xidel's output file, it is indeed possible with either `--output-footer` or `--output-separator` flags depending on what you mean.

`--output-footer` appends a string to the end of all output (for instance a multiple line breaks).

`--output-separator` appends a string to the end each item.